# How can I pass a unit test immediately after an expected method is called on the mock object?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

When working with Rhino.Mocks with a mock object in hand:

Is there a way to pass a unit-test once an expected method is called without executing the lines after the call to this expected method?

Thanks

Comment: So you want the mock to be able to signal that the test is complete ?

Comment: Yes; the reason is if I do not 'arrrange' some couple of object which are touched after this method call, I have an exception. And I don't find it meaningful to enlarge my test just to prevent an exception while I am convinved that the test is passed by calling that expected method.

Comment: I think you should rather fix your design than obfuscate the execution flow of your tests. Without knowing more details it's hard to tell what the problem is, but it sounds like you have a method that does more than one thing (the thing you're testing plus the thing you want to skip), violating the single responsibility principle.

Comment: +1 for yuor comment. I think I have to agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since RhinoMocks 3.5 you can use nice `AssertWasCalled()`

```
this.Service.BuldMessage("messageId");
this.Service.AssertWasCalled(x => x.GenerateMessage("messageId"), messageId));
```

- [Beautiful (nontrivial) Code - Rhino Mocks 3.5's AssertWasCalled](http://ayende.com/blog/3412/beautiful-nontrivial-code-rhino-mocks-3-5s-assertwascalled)

**EDIT: Answer to comment**

RhinoMock is not in charge to change test execution flow, so you have to use NUnit asserts,
[Assert.Pass()](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5) utility method allows you to immediately end the test, recording it as successful:

```
if (this.Service.AssertWasCalled(...)))
{
   Assert.Pass("well done");
}
```

PS: as others suggested consider redesing of unit test which forced you to do such conditional test exit.

Comment: I know this. But what I mean is: Once it is called, STOP executing method because the test is already passed as expected thing happened.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `AssertWasCalled()` in Rhino.Mocks

Your expectation that the test should stop if the method is called and should not run the following lines means that you have written the test wrong. Have the assert (Nunit or otherwise) as the last line of the test and split the test. You are probably testing two things and that is not unit testing. Don't have such kind of branching flow in tests. All the lines in the tests should be executed. And ideally, every test should have only one assert.

With the kind of flow you are expecting, you lose the feedback you get from the tests when they fail, as well. You don't know, by just looking at the test name, what failed.